# Formatting string from ArrayList

Tags: android, formatting

I have two ArrayLists like:

infromation, id, key3, something,...          -> this is array1

some_value,1539,value3,anything,...           -> this is array2

I want to join key1 and value1, key2 and value2, etc. like this example:

```
information...........some_value
id....................1539
key3..................value3
something.............anything
```

I tried with this code:

```
Integer dotsNeeded = 50 - array1.length();

String repeated = new String(new char[dotsNeeded]).replace("\0", ".");
finaArray.add( array1.get(i) + repeated + array2.get(i) );
```

but the result is not good as different letters need different space.

Comment: if you don't mind then use HashMap instead of ArrayList

Comment: Why would you need to format a string like that? Maybe there is another solution for this

Comment: To show strings from array1 and array2 like table of content. All this values finally must be in only one TextView.

Comment: You're better off with a listview and a custom layout which contains two textviews to display two values next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ArrayList<String> list1;
ArrayList<String> list2;
ArrayList<String> formatted = new ArrayList<>();

int longest;
for (String str : list1) {
    if (longest < str.length()) longest = str.length();
}
longest += 10;

for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
    String item1 = list1.get(i);
    String periods = new String(new char[longest-item1.length()]).replace("\0", ".");
    formatted.add(item1 + periods + list2.get(i));
}
```

It finds the longest item in first list, then adds extra periods with `longest += 10`. Then items of same index are concatenated with the periods between them.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
int lineSize = 20;

for (int i=0 ; i<key.size() ; i++){
    builder.append(key.get(i));
    builder.append(new String(new char[lineSize-key.get(i).length()]).replace("\0", "."));
    builder.append(value.get(i));
    builder.append("\n");
}

Log.d(TAG, builder.toString());
```